# Compare String Array with Dictionary in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, string, dictionary

I have string Array `let filterClassName = ["A","B"]`

Now I have Dictionary which looks like:

```
var responseArray: [[String: Any]] = []

responseArray.append(["id": 1,"name": "Prateek", "className": "A"])
responseArray.append(["id": 1,"name": "rateek", "className": "B"])
responseArray.append(["id": 3,"name": "ateek", "className": "C"])
responseArray.append(["id": 4,"name": "teek", "className": "D"])
responseArray.append(["id": 5,"name": "eek", "className": "A"])
responseArray.append(["id": 6,"name": "ek", "className": "E"])
```

Now from `responseArray` which is my Dictionary I want all values which matches my className mentioned in `filterClassName`

So, I should get output as Array of:

> ["id": 1,"name": "Prateek", "className": "A"],["id": 1,"name":
>   "rateek", "className": "B"],["id": 5,"name": "eek", "className": "A"]

Thanks in advance!

This is what I have tried:

```
for value in filterClassName {
    let cal = responseArray.filter { (($0["className"] as! String).contains(value)) }
    for value in cal {
        let valuesss = value
        print ("valuesss" + String(describing: valuesss))
    }
}
```

My above answer is very basic, but I want something like this to work:

```
let cal = responseArray.filter { (($0["className"] as! String).contains(filterClassName)) }
```

In short, single line for filtering and no for loops as I hate them!

Comment: What have you tried? We don't like answering questions that show no prior effort.

Comment: This is an inappropriate use of a dictionary – you should create a structure instead in order to represent a response. Filtering then becomes simpler.

Comment: @Hamish This is data I am getting from webservice which comes in Dictionary. I am looking for less code

Comment: @P.J Rather than looking for the shortest code look for the most efficient code.

Comment: @P.J Side note: you should really use an array literal instead of such repeated `append` calls

Comment: @Alexander Any example you have?

Comment: @P.J. the general syntax is like: `let array = [a, b, c]`. It's explained in the language guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite close, but it's the other way round:

```
let filteredItems = responseArray.filter{ filterClassName.contains($0["className"] as! String) }
```

---

However – as Hamish mentioned in the comments – it's more efficient to use a custom struct.

Your code:

```
let filterClassName = ["A","B"]

var responseArray: [[String: Any]] = []

responseArray.append(["id": 1,"name": "Prateek", "className": "A"])
responseArray.append(["id": 1,"name": "rateek", "className": "B"])
responseArray.append(["id": 3,"name": "ateek", "className": "C"])
responseArray.append(["id": 4,"name": "teek", "className": "D"])
responseArray.append(["id": 5,"name": "eek", "className": "A"])
responseArray.append(["id": 6,"name": "ek", "className": "E"])
```

Code to add:

```
struct Student {
    let name, className : String
    let id : Int

    init?(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
        guard let id = dictionary["id"] as? Int,
            let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
            let className = dictionary["className"] as? String else { return nil }
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.className = className
    }
}

let students = responseArray.flatMap { Student(dictionary:$0) }
let filteredItems = students.filter{ filterClassName.contains($0.className) }
print(filteredItems)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was expecting!

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the `filterClassName` Array contains the class name.

```
let filteredResponse = responseArray.filter { filterClassName.contains($0["className"] as! String) }
```